# How to refresh record when user presses Cancel button in Salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, publisher

I'm writing a visualforce page as a custom object action for Salesforce1 app accessed on user's mobile devices (e.g. iPhone) and need to **refresh** the detail screen when the user clicks the **Cancel** button.

[image]

I can do this easily when the user clicks the **Submit** button (code shown below) but I can't figure out how to force the publisher to refresh when the user clicks the **Cancel** button.

Normally, if the user clicks the **Submit** button then I can simply subscribe to the `publisher.post` event and fire a `publisher.close` like this:

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.post", onData:function(e) {
  // do something ...
  Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});
});
```

I read the Salesforce1 [cheatsheet](http://res.cloudinary.com/hy4kyit2a/image/upload/s1_dev_cheatsheet_cheatsheet.pdf) and it mentions there is a `publisher.clearPanelState` event. I subscribed to this event but I can't figure out how to force the publisher to refresh the data so the user's device has the latest information rather than the stale cached copy.

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe({name: "publisher.clearPanelState", onData:function(e) {
    // when user clicks 'Cancel' button this is logged and I see it
    console.log('publisher.clearPanelState');
    // but neither this causes a refresh
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});
    // nor this line causes a refresh
    Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.refresh", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});
}});
```

The use case is that a record may have a "status" field and this action should only be used when "status=X". The record in the Salesforce database is "status=Y" but since the data may be cached on the user's device they may still see "status=X". When the user tries to use my publisher action I detect this scenario and inform the user they can't take action. I can tell them they need to refresh their data (click cancel button then pull to refresh, etc..) but it would be awesome if I could automate the refresh when the user clicks the Cancel button.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have solution for this problem? in our case, we need to update the related list as we are adding child record in custom action.